# Parse error on comments in Agda for Emacs?

Tags: agda

I've tried type checking modules programs that import modules from `Builtin` or the standard library, it always brings me to some module in the particular library that I'm importing from and says there's a parse error on a comment. When it does this on a file in the standard library I just delete the comment, but it won't let me edit files in `Builtin`. I'm using Emacs 25.1 and Agda 2.4.2. What should I do? Specifically, I'm importing `Agda.Builtin.Float` and it's giving me a parse error on

```
{-# COMPILED_DATA_UHC Bool_BOOL_ _FALSE_ _TRUE_ #-}
```

in `Agda.Builtin.Bool`

Comment: It seems there is a mismatch between your Agda version and the version of the standard library. Which is your version of the standard library? Did you install Agda and the standard library from some distribution (e.j. Ubuntu)?

Comment: @asr Yeah I installed agda from the wiki (I thought I installed 2.5.2 but whatever I guess) then later I installed the standard library .13 also from the wiki. I'm using a windows machine, if that's relevant.

Comment: The wiki tells you [which version of the stdlib has been tested with which version of Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary). You're using a fairly old version of Agda so you should download an old version of the standard library too; 0.8.1 in your case.